# C# Expressions: How is this AutoMapper code working?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, automapper

So I'm using the AutoMapper library, and I'm trying to understand how AutoMapper is mapping from the source to the destination property.  I think I'm just missing a key part of C#'s expression syntax/Linq support.  If anyone could explain to me what exactly is happening here I would appreciate it.

Here is an example of some AutoMapper configuration code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceModel, DestinationModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Summary, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Summary))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Year, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Year));
```

I'm most perplexed by the line `dest => dest.Summary`... How exactly is `src.Summary` being mapped in to `dest.Summary`?  How does evaluating the expression `dest.Summary` tell AutomMapper to map in to this property?  I'm guessing there is some powerful lambda/expression features that I don't understand or am missing.

Thanks!

Comment: It may be helpful to look at the AutoMapper source code, available at https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.

Comment: This link may also be helpful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper

Comment: `ForMember` operates on the types you specify as the constructor generic parameters - `SourceModel` and `DestinationModel`. It is just convention to use the lambda argument names of `dest` and `src`.
The `ForMember` declarations you specified are not necessary as automapper will automagically map public properties with same name and implicit type conversion (i.e. if `Year` is an `int` in both `SourceDestination` and `DestinationModel`).

Comment: Expression.Compile is a magical, magical thing. You can compile expressions, then invoke them as functions later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automapper is simply getting information on the types you wish to map and the `PropertyInfo` of the properties to be matched.  If you would like to understand what it is doing, try to play around a little bit with this:

```
public static class PropertyExtensions
{
    public static System.Reflection.PropertyInfo ToPropertyInfo<T, TProperty>(this Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propExpression) where T : class
    {
        if (propExpression == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propExpression");
        var expr = propExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (expr == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Property expression is not a member expression.", "propExpression");
        var propInfo = expr.Member as System.Reflection.PropertyInfo;
        if (propInfo == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Member expression is not for a property.", "propExpression");
        return propInfo;
    }
}
public static class TestIt<T> where T : class
{
    public static void PrintProperty<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propExpression)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(propExpression.ToPropertyInfo());
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestIt<string>.PrintProperty(s => s.Length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear specifically what you're asking, there are several parts:

- The Fluent Interface.  When you call `CreateMap()` it will return something like `IFluentInterface<TSource, TDestination>`.  This is the main interface to define mappings.  Most members of this interface will return this interface as well, which allows you to make several `.ForMember()` calls

  - The `CreateMap()` call also sets the Generic types.  The types you pass will be applied to all relevant members of the interface, giving you a strongly-typed interface (a "closed generic").  Without this calls like `dest => dest.Summary` would not be possible (you'd probably have to specify them by name, which is fragile).
- The `ForMember()` call takes two parameters.

  - The first is most likely an `Expression<Func<TDestination, object>>`.  This is a mouthful, but it specifies that you can provide a Lamdda expression against the `TDestination` type (closed by the preceding `CreateMap()` call) that retuns an object.  Within this method it's likely resolving the specified object to a MemberInfo, which lets automapper retrieve the metadata and value of the specified member.
  - The second member is another AutoMapper type; it will be a type used to instruct AutoMapper how to set the value for the specified member.  It could be provided an argument such as the `opt.MapFrom<TSource>()` call in your example, or probably others to do things like use a constant value.

These calls are likely used during AutoMapper initialization to define the configuration for the mapping from one type to another.  Basically these are instructions; AutoMapper may or may not have a seperate set of code that follows these instructions to perform the actual mapping.

---

[Here's another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression) that shows how the internals of calls like `ForMember(dest => dest.Summary)`  are possibly implemented.  This covers looking up the `MemberInfo` of the specified member.

[Here's some basic info](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) on Fluent Interfaces/